# Drupal Views an NodeReferences: Linking to URL in referenced node

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have a cck-node with some node-references like PDF-files, videos and so on. Now I want to build a view that lists all those files, which i already have. Yet I can only get the links linking to the referenced node. I'd like to have them link to the file in the referenced node.

Hope a generic example makes it clearer:

--

## A Sample Product

Lorem Ipsum…

### Relating Files:

#### Manuals

- Manual A (should link to file instead of node)
- Manual B (should link to file instead of node)

#### Movies

- Movie (should link to file instead of node)

--

Hope someone can help me with this.

**Note:** Client preferes to have it build only with views - no template files or such because he's familiar with drupal but not with templates etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this module: http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_views - lets you format a nodereference field to show different pieces of the referenced node.